# int parse not adding to list properly

Tags: c#, list, int

I have a textbox that takes a int input from a user, I then use a loop to add each digit to my list integerList. But when I display the list in my listbox it only displays the first int. For instance if the user inputs 12345 it should show as a list in the listbox:

```
Listbox output should look like this:
1
2
3
4
5
```

This is the code:

```
        List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
        for (int a = 0; a < textBox1.Text.Length; a++)
        {
            integerList.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text[a].ToString()));
            listBox1.DataSource = integerList;

        }
```

Comment: I don't see why your code wouldn't work. Maybe try moving `listBox1.DataSource = integerList;` to after the for-loop.

Comment: Yeah I don't see why it wouldn't work either. However, as mentioned that expression should definitely be outside of the for loop, regardless of whether or not it solves the problem.

Comment: I assume the reason it doesn't work if you have the assignment inside the loop is that a) the Listbox doesn't track *changes* to the data source; it assumes it's static, and b) it checks to see if a new source is reference equal to the old source, and bails if that's the case. So the first time around, it sets the source to a single-element list. Because of point a), additional element adds aren't noticed, and because of b), setting the source again is a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you take the line

```
listBox1.DataSource = integerList;
```

out of the loop?

```
    List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
    for (int a = 0; a < textBox1.Text.Length; a++)
    {
        integerList.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text[a].ToString()));
    }

    listBox1.DataSource = integerList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use next code for achieving exactly what you want

```
listBox1.DataSource = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
```